# Pressing multiple buttons at the same time

Tags: android, multi-touch

I'm working on an app which presents users with four buttons and a timer. The users then tap as fast as they can, each user on his own button, and the one with the most taps at the end wins.

I can't use onClick here, because it locks up the UI thread until the button is released, effectively blocking other button presses. I have searched around for a bit and found that I could use onTouch, but it doesn't work the way I want it to. If a user has touched and is still holding a button, any subsequent touches on other buttons will behave as though this first button was pressed.

Someone suggested the use of an image, transparent and stretched across the entire visible UI. One could then read any touches on this imageview and assign a touch to a particular button based on the coordinates of the press. (I guess I would take a screenshot of my UI with the four buttons visible, open it in paint and write down the coordinates of the borders for each button, then use those coordinates in the code to figure out which button the user was trying to press.)

Can anyone help me with this method of work, give me a quick example, or link to where I can learn how to do it and implement it in my app? It would be much appreciated.

**TL;DR: How to use an image, transparent and stretched across the entire visible UI and read the coordinates of each press (even if multiple at once)?**